# Update columns in MySQL depending on cell value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update multiple cells in a MySQL table depending on value.

I find that if I take a field called engagement I can update it one at a time like so:

```
UPDATE billing_info_test 
SET Engagement='800000039768' 
WHERE Engagement IS NULL and LinkedAccountId = '12345678910'
```

However, if I try to do multiple at a time it fails and I get an error:

```
UPDATE billing_info_test 
SET Engagement='800000039768' 
WHERE Engagement IS NULL and LinkedAccountId = '12345678910' 
AND SET Engagement='800000039768' 
WHERE Engagement IS NULL and LinkedAccountId = '3542123267612';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET Engagement='800000039768' WHERE Engagement IS NULL and LinkedAccountId = '30' at line 1

Is it incorrect to use AND between these statements? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a CASE statement:

```
UPDATE billing_info_test 
SET 
  Engagement = CASE 
    WHEN LinkedAccountId = '12345678910' THEN 'something'
    WHEN LinkedAccountId = '3542123267612' THEN 'somethingelse'
    WHEN LinkedAccountId IN ('354', '123', '000') THEN 'somethingelsetoo'
    ELSE 'default'
  END
WHERE Engagement IS NULL
```

Comment: Maybe adding an `ELSE` statement could be safe, to avoid updating the other rows...

Comment: THANKS!!! I will try it out on a test table and see how it goes! :) Could you provide an example of using ELSE in this statement?

Comment: `WHERE Engagement IS NULL` makes sure that only NULL columns will be updated. Also the ELSE statement would be ELSE NULL, right? It is not needed.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks! I think this will work. Will give that a try.

Comment: @bluethundr use nCessity's answer.I did not see that the values in both cases are the same. Deleting in 1 min.

Comment: @bluethundr after your comments I think you need a CASE statement.

Comment: Thanks again! That does work. However, the `Engagement` will be different based on the `LinkedAccountId` (aws account number). 

But a lot of them will be the same. The `Engagement` only differs from time to time. Is there a way to make this more efficient if a lot of them use the same `Engagement` and only some differ?

Comment: See my edited answer. You can use IN and an ELSE part if needed.

Comment: Ok, that's great! I will try that. Really appreciate the info!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that statement is not correct ([MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html))

I assume you want to put **the same** value into the `Engagement` column of **different** rows:

Try this:

```
UPDATE billing_info_test 
  SET Engagement='800000039768' 
  WHERE Engagement IS NULL AND (
    LinkedAccountId = '12345678910' 
    OR LinkedAccountId = '3542123267612'
  );
```

In the case that you want to put **different** values into the `Engagement`column of several rows, you need to issue several independent statements.

Comment: They could also use `LinkedAccountId IN ('12345678910', '3542123267612')` as a shortcut for `(LinkedAccountId = '12345678910' OR LinkedAccountId = '3542123267612')`.

Comment: Ok thanks. The value of `Engagement` will depend on the value of `LinkedAccountId`.

Comment: @bluethundr maybe you can elaborate on the dependency of Engagement and LinkedAccountId?

Comment: Just so happens that SOME of the `Engagement` numbers will be the same. But they do depend on the `LinkedAccountId` value.

Comment: Sure, `LinkedAccountId` is an AWS Account number. And `Engagement` is a code used to bill different business who use the same AWS account and other accounts.  Sometimes the same engagement will be used in different AWS accounts. Let me know if that's clear or not, please.

Comment: In light of this, several independent statements, or as @forpas proposes, a `CASE` will be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression to make the value you assign dependent on another column.

```
UPDATE billing_info_test 
SET Engagement= 
    CASE LinkedAccountId
        WHEN '12345678910' THEN '800000039768'
        WHEN '3542123267612' THEN '800000039768'
    END
WHERE Engagement IS NULL AND LinkedAccountId IN ('12345678910', '3542123267612');
```